# Im trying to create a three way interaction plot but my x axis labels are messed up

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to create a three way interaction plot but my x axis labels  not according to my independent variable of P treatment which is `"0,3,6,12,36"`.

I have tried to put in the code, `levels = c("0","3","6","12","36")` but it throws out this....

[image]

```r
ggplot(tg2, aes(
         x = factor(interaction(cultivar, P),levels = c("0","3","6","12","36")),
         y = shoot, fill = waterlogg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge",colour="black",
           size=.1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=shoot-se, ymax=shoot+se),
                size=0.3,
                width=.2,            
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~cultivar, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Can you do a ``dput()`` of your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a small example of reproducible data, it is hard to propose a good answer but based on the code you wrote, I have the feeling that trying to do the interaction of `cultivar` with `P` generates `NA`, so instead, maybe you should try:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tg2, aes( x = as.factor(P), y = shoot, fill = waterlogg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar((aes(ymin = shoot-se, ymax = shoot+se)), size = 0.3, 
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(.9))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("0","3","6","12","36"))+
  facet_wrap(.~cultivar)
```

Does it look better ?

If not, please consider providing a reproducible example of your data (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: That worked! Than you very much! It worked without needing to add this line...+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("0","3","6","12","36"))

Comment: Glad it help you to solve your issue. Please next time consider to provide a reproducible example of your dataset, it will be much easier to help you ;)